# REGEXP not working with character names

Tags: mysql, regex

According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html, i can use `[.plus-sign.]` instead of `[.+.]`

So then why does the below two queries give me different results in MySql 5.6.17 :

```
select case when '+123' regexp '^[.+.][0-9]+$'
then 1
else 2
end;
```

(gives Result 1)

```
select case when '+123' regexp '^[.plus-sign.][0-9]+$'
then 1
else 2
end;
```

(gives Result 2)

Using character names would be pretty neat if it worked as expected. Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `[[ character class ]]` like this:

```
select '+123' regexp '^[[.plus-sign.]][0-9]+$';
1
```

Comment: Bingo! It was driving me crazy.

Comment: Glad to know it helped.